# How to get v2 About.LargestChangeId in case of google drive v3?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-drive-api

I in the process of porting my [Google Drive v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/about-sdk) code to [Google drive v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk).

In Google drive v2 there is a method [About.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/about/get) which has a property called virtual long?

```
 LargestChangeId { get; set; }
```

I am having trouble finding this  property in [About.get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/about/get)
method in the Google Drive V3

What is the replacement of this property in V3?

Comment: The first thing you should do is check the documentation to see if the Google drive api supports something like that.   Then edit your question and include your code show us what you have tried and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Comment: @DalmTo Edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: I have edited and applied to reopen your question.   If we get it open again i will try to help but if not you can check out this page https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/v2-to-v3-reference it points out how to map the changes between the two APIs.   If the question reopens post a comment and i will be notified.

Comment: @DalmTo thanks I found the solution in the link you provided. Now largestChangeId is changed to changes.getStartPageToken.

Comment: Its a very good question and should not have been closed to begin with.  In the future just watching your wording be very clear and concise write your question as if you are talking to someone who has no idea what you are even doing.   You are just lucky i know the API enough that i knew what you were asking and could fix your question in order to help you.  Welcome to stack :)

Answer (score 1):

If you check [V2 to v3 reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/v2-to-v3-reference) it will help you in your process of upgrading to the new api.

You will find that largestChangeId is actually now found under changes.getStartPageToken.